# Вставка html в textarea визуального редактора Imperavi

Tags: jquery, wysiwyg, php, yii

Есть imperavi в качестве плагина. В документации написано, что для вставки html (я беру нужный мне html из БД Ajax-ом) нужно использовать такую конструкцию:

```
$('#redactor').redactor('insertHtmlAdvanced', 'your code');
```

Сам редактор на странице пользователя представлен в виде textarea с id='Additional_text' и перед ней div с классом redactor_box

При попытке сделать хотя бы это: 
      $('#Additional_text').redactor('insertHtmlAdvanced', '123'); ничего не происходит. Консоль в фаербаге так же не ругается.
    При попытке сделать тоже самое для дива выдается ошибка вида Error: No such method "insertHtmlAdvanced" for Redactor
    Естественно вариант $('#additional_row .redactor_editor').text( '123'); 123 вставляет в редактор, но если там будет html со всеми тегами, то он вставится в сыром виде и будет дополнительно обрамлен тегами самим редактором (простейшее форматирование параграфы и дивы). 
    Собственно вопрос: как заставить этот редактор выполнять основную его задачу, то есть дать возможность редактировать заранее введенный текст?

UPDATE:
 Собственно на сколько я понял insertHtmlAdvanced не работает нормально. Решение - использовать   $('#Additional_text').redactor('set', '123');

Answer (score 1):

```
var redactor = $('#redactor').redactor('insertHtmlAdvanced', 'your code');
redactor.setHtml('code');
```

Comment: TypeError: redactor.setHtml is not a function

Comment: @makbeth сам редактор создается? Данный код я взял с официального сайта. Попробуйте обновить библиотеку.

Comment: С редактором все норм. Он работает нормально. Только вот эта штука работать не хочет. Версия редактора последняя у меня.

Answer (score 0):

```
`$('#redactor').redactor('insertHtmlAdvanced', 'your code');`
```

а вот етот код где написан?

Comment: Это пример из документации по Imperavi http://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/api/#api-insertHtmlAdvanced

Comment: напиши тогда какой код на странице у тебя

Comment: Я же уже писал:  $('#Additional_text').redactor('insertHtmlAdvanced', '123');